# Select patterns from mail body - VBA

Tags: vba, email, excel, outlook

I receive multiple mails, where I have to do a pattern search and get the results to an array. is there any easy way of doing it in excel vba?

My mail content looks like this :

Selection   : 
Your Selection

Description : My description

Items       :

ITEM.12345.XYZ

ITEM.56789.KHI

ITEM.54567.YHT

This is a sample mail.

## ............................

I need to grep for all the lines starting with ITEM. I can do it, by this way :

```
aryLines = Split(MyMail.Body, vbCrLf)
```

Loop through aryLines

Find the match

I am looking for an easy solution, as the number of matching lines varies and sometimes it can go over 1000 and sometimes less than 10. I want to populate these values to an xls sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong though but IMHO splitting the body into the array as you have done is the fastest way. I then loop through the array and in conjunction with `INSTR()` or `LEFT()` get the relevant lines. In your case I would you `LEFT()`. In fact I use it all the time.

For example

```
aryLines = Split(MyMail.Body, vbCrLf)

For i = LBound(aryLines) To UBound(aryLines)
    If InStr(1, aryLines(i), "ITEM", vbTextCompare) Then

    End If
Next i
```

The other option is to export the data immediately into Excel after splitting it into the array and then using the `.AutoFilter`

```
aryLines = Split(aaa, vbCrLf)

oXLWorksheet.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(aryLines), 1).Value = _
oXLAP.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(aryLines)
```

Once the data is exported, you can use the `Autofilter` to delete the rows which you don't want. An example can be seen [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631363/how-to-copy-a-line-in-excel-using-a-specific-word-and-pasting-to-another-excel-s). This example copies the filtered range but you can edit it to delete the range

The criteria for `Autofilter` will be `Criteria1:="<>ITEM*"`. This means filter cells which do not begin with `ITEM`